# how to use DataGridViewButtonCell in DataGridViewButtonRow?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with the last column to be `DataGridViewButtonCell` (for Editing).
I want to do the following:
When the mouse is on a row, the "edit" button will be showed, otheriwse, if will be hidden.

I tried many ways to do it , but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the DataGridViewButtonCell to DataGridViewTextBoxCell.

Here is a sample.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, 
                                         DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; index++)
        {
            DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.Rows[index];
            if (index == dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
            {
                DataGridViewTextBoxCell txtCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                dr.Cells[0] = txtCell;
            }
            else
            {
                DataGridViewButtonCell buttonCell = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
                dr.Cells[0] = buttonCell;
            }
        }
    }
}
```